# get all startup processes in windows

Tags: c#, windows, startup

I want to list all the processes that runs on windows startup using c#. I've tried the code

```
string keyPath = @"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";       
RegistryKey key = 
      Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
key.GetValueNames()
key.GetValue(Processname).toString()
```

This code is giving me some startup items that I can see in taskbar startup, but not all items.

Using windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: There are so, so many different ways a program can run on boot or log on in Windows. That registry key (both HKLM and HKCU), scheduled tasks, weird shell tricks, etc.

Comment: Please give an example of an application that is starting that is that listed in the registry.  This will help people in pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @BlackFrog For example I can see Adobe cs6 Service manager in task manager startup option as well as in Local machine run registry and my application too . But the problem is that I am not getting all the applications that I can see in startup option of task manager. In short I want to know that is there any other place other than run and runonce where I can get information about all the startup programs

Comment: Registry redirection, plus all the reg keys that you missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're many ways to launch a program at startup in Windows. At least you also should check HKCU (current user) registry hive and RunOnce, RunOnceEx subkeys in both hives.